# Function not responding if the element is not in the page from the start

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".todo-task").click(function(){
        $(".todo-task").css('background-color','green');
    });
});
```

the problem is that "todo-task" is not an element which is present when the page is loaded, but it's appended to the page with another function.
I think that that fact above prevents the function I wrote from taking place, because if I paste the exact same function in the controller when the "todo-task" is present in the page, everything works perfectly.

What should I do?

Comment: Google jQuery event delegation. This should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".todo-task", function(){
        $(".todo-task").css('background-color','green');
    });
});
```

Note that `document` can -and should- be replaced by the closest parent that initially exists (for performance - no need to watch the whole document when you know it's going to be in a particular div).